# How to update a column by subtracting from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `cart` and `cages`, I am trying to update the 'remaining' column by checking the item_name for all entries in `cart` and subtracting the quantity in the corresponding tables.

```
[cages]
id     name     total     remaining     
-----------------------------------
1      Cage1     10       10
2      Cage2     15       15
3      Cage3     10       10


[cart]
id    item_name     quantity  
-----------------------------------
1     Cage1         2
2     Book4         3
```

There are several tables in the database that would need to be checked upon purchase however, I am not sure what would be the best way of performing these queries without joining all tables. This is the query I have been attempting to use.

```sql
UPDATE cages 
SET remaining = (remaining - cart.quantity 
WHERE cart.item_name = cages.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must join the tables before you can update

```
UPDATE cages 
JOIN cart on cart.item_name = cages.name
SET remaining = (remaining - cart.quantity)
```